# Replace tabs with spaces

Tags: string, file, rust

Text file for my database (homework):

```
'Angola Africa '   
 'Burkina Faso  Africa'  
'Burundi    Africa'  
...... ()
```

I want to replace these tabs with spaces. I tried:

```
fn main() {    
    let data_file = File::open("raw_data2.txt").unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(data_file);
    let mut sql_commands = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .open("SQL_input.sql")
        .unwrap();

    for (index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
        let Line: String = line.unwrap(); // Ignore errors.
        Line = Line.replace("   "," ");
        let SQL_query: Vec<&str> = Line.split(' ').collect::<Vec<_>>();
        println!("{}. {}", index + 1, Line); 
        if let Err(e) = writeln!(sql_commands, "{}", SQL_query[0]) {
            eprintln!("Couldn't write to file: {}", e);}
        }    
    }  
}
```

And `replace` did nothing! What else can I do?

Comment: It's worth noting that using `Line` and `SQL_querry` as local variables is unusual in conventional Rust code. Generally, we use `snake_case` for local variables (`line` and `sql_query`).

Answer (score 4):

In your current code, you're replacing three spaces with one space. No tabs are harmed. Consider replacing your `"   "` with `"\t"`.

```
Line = Line.replace("\t"," ");
```